# Api usage report for more than 7 days

Tags: api, reporting

Is it possible to get a plot of the API usage for more than 7 days? Also, is it possible to get data at a user level, as in a report of xyz@test.com's API usage over the last 45 days.

Answer (score 2):

There is already report created in every org for this. Click the Reports tab and view the "API Usage Last 7 Days" report under the Administrative Reports folder. This will show you how many calls each app/person made in the last 7 days.

For more granular details you can Event logging https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this report gives API usage of only  7 days. Is there any way to customize this report to get API usage for more than 7 days.

Comment: nope.  you will need to use Event log files for that. Please check the link mentioned in above answer.